# overlay in html fix

Tags: html, css, overlay, alpha

As you can see here:

http://clients.noxxie.nl/rashosting/

I am using overlay in the image lighter black background.
but the text is also in overlay and that is not to happen.

Does anybody now how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.text` container has an `opacity` of 0.5 and is being inherited by its sibling content. You can fix it by using an `rgba` color on the container instead of opacity (though there is sparse support in IE (IE9 and above i believe) like so:

```
.text {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Or you can use a 1x1 semi-transparent png image as a background on that container. Another method would be to create an overlay div, absolutely positioned to cover the `.text` container with the opacity and a `z-index` low enough to stay behind everything else. Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="overlay">&nbsp;</div>
```

You can place the `.overlay` div inside of your `.text` container right at the bottom of the div.

**CSS**

```
.text {
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
}

.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
  background-color:black;
  opacity:0.5
  z-index:1;
}
```